# encoding in doctrine or twig have problems

Tags: php, symfony, encoding, doctrine-orm, twig

I have a project that written by symfony framework and use doctrine as orm and twig dor template engine.

Project no have any problem on my system(local), but on server: That have problem in encoding.
I use utf8 encodin and utf8_general_ci as collection charset.

as i say, i no have any problem in local and my data is right on server in phpmyadmin, but no on website's pages(my symfony project), I know that pages have true encoding because static text in twig is right and only data that read from mysql have problem
plz see site:

http://iaubir.cloudsite.ir/blog/zeinali

thank you for Your help

---

Edit: This Problem is only for imported row by phpmyadmin(import structure & data), if i login to admin panel and post a new post, that will display correctly

I update a field that value is "دروس" and now display correctly in my site, but in phpmyadmin that have "Ø¯Ø±ÙˆØ³" value
I try Detect encoding of "Ø¯Ø±ÙˆØ³" by [This Site](http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=en) , that detect:
source encoding: utf-8 displayed as: windows-1258

Comment: sometimes you need to drop all tables data and insert new value to table only by your site panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is with your imported data, I wouldn't use phpadmin for such task.

Try this to export the database:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p database -r utf8.dump
```

and this to import it:

```
mysql -uroot -p --default-character-set=utf8 database
mysql> SOURCE utf8.dump
```

Comment: I no have ssh connection to server, Limited host

Comment: @ghanbari, have you tried to export it locally with mysqldump (with the -r option) and the import it with phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes, That was problem with my host, i change host and now evrything is right